# Why CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH gives NULL and -1 in sql server table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

sql:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  for columns like rank(id,null) CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH is NULL and for the column id(varchar(max),null) CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH is -1.
```

why cant i get the maximum length for  rank(id,null) - 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A value of -1 means it's a varchar(max) or nvarchar(max) field.

A null value means that it's a number that doesn't have a length.

Comment: why cant i get the maximum length for rank(id,null) - 4

Comment: What is it you're really trying to do? Focus your question.

Comment: I want the storage space for the field rank(id,null) where id is int so i want to get storage space - 4 bytes @Lamak

Comment: I still don't understand what you're asking, sorry. The storage for a varchar(max) is the length of the string in bytes plus at least four bytes for the length. The storage for an nvarchar(max) field is two times the length of the string in bytes, plus at least four bytes for the length. There is additional alignment overhead and paging stuff, depending on what exactly you're trying to compute.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers are not characters, so they do not have a `character_maximum_length`.

`(max)` columns are limited to ~2gb of data (2^31-1 bytes (2 GB)), so however many that is in characters (costs twice as much in bytes per `nvarchar()` character vs `varchar()` characters), is represented by `-1`.